# Threadpool in C

Tags: c, multithreading, threadpool

I'm new to threads, so I used this article to learn how to create a threadpool.
[https://nachtimwald.com/2019/04/12/thread-pool-in-c/](https://stackoverflow.com)

The problem is that when I use a large number of tasks, everything works well, but if the number of tasks is small, then the task processing function is not called. `void worker(void *arg)`
[image: strange program execution behavior]

For example, if the number of threads is 4, and I create 24 tasks, then they will almost never be executed. (see the picture).
And the smaller the number of tasks, the less probability the function will work. `void worker(void *arg)`

***I'm not sure, but it seems to me that the main problem is that the thread does not have time to be created, as the task is already in the Queue.
The thread is created using pthread_create() function***

**tpool.h**

```
#ifndef __TPOOL_H__
#define __TPOOL_H__

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct tpool;
typedef struct tpool tpool_t;

typedef void (*thread_func_t)(void *arg);

tpool_t *tpool_create(size_t num);
void tpool_destroy(tpool_t *tm);

bool tpool_add_work(tpool_t *tm, thread_func_t func, void *arg);
void tpool_wait(tpool_t *tm);

#endif /* __TPOOL_H__ */
```

**tpool.c**

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include "tpool.h"


struct tpool_work {
    thread_func_t      func;
    void              *arg;
    struct tpool_work *next;
};
typedef struct tpool_work tpool_work_t;

struct tpool {
    tpool_work_t    *work_first;
    tpool_work_t    *work_last;
    pthread_mutex_t  work_mutex;
    pthread_cond_t   work_cond;
    pthread_cond_t   working_cond;
    size_t           working_cnt;
    size_t           thread_cnt;
    bool             stop;
};

static tpool_work_t *tpool_work_create(thread_func_t func, void *arg)
{
    tpool_work_t *work;

    if (func == NULL)
        return NULL;

    work       = malloc(sizeof(*work));
    work->func = func;
    work->arg  = arg;
    work->next = NULL;
    return work;
}

static void tpool_work_destroy(tpool_work_t *work)
{
    if (work == NULL)
        return;
    free(work);
}


static tpool_work_t *tpool_work_get(tpool_t *tm)
{
    tpool_work_t *work;

    if (tm == NULL)
        return NULL;

    work = tm->work_first;
    if (work == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if (work->next == NULL) {
        tm->work_first = NULL;
        tm->work_last  = NULL;
    } else {
        tm->work_first = work->next;
    }

    return work;
}


static void *tpool_worker(void *arg)
{
    tpool_t      *tm = arg;
    tpool_work_t *work;

    while (1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(tm->work_mutex));

        while (tm->work_first == NULL && !tm->stop)
            pthread_cond_wait(&(tm->work_cond), &(tm->work_mutex));

        if (tm->stop)
            break;

        work = tpool_work_get(tm);
        tm->working_cnt++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tm->work_mutex));

        if (work != NULL) {
            work->func(work->arg);
            tpool_work_destroy(work);
        }

        pthread_mutex_lock(&(tm->work_mutex));
        tm->working_cnt--;
        if (!tm->stop && tm->working_cnt == 0 && tm->work_first == NULL)
            pthread_cond_signal(&(tm->working_cond));
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tm->work_mutex));
    }

    tm->thread_cnt--;
    pthread_cond_signal(&(tm->working_cond));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tm->work_mutex));
    return NULL;
}


tpool_t *tpool_create(size_t num)
{
    tpool_t   *tm;
    pthread_t  thread;
    size_t     i;

    if (num == 0)
        num = 2;

    tm             = calloc(1, sizeof(*tm));
    tm->thread_cnt = num;

    pthread_mutex_init(&(tm->work_mutex), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(tm->work_cond), NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&(tm->working_cond), NULL);

    tm->work_first = NULL;
    tm->work_last  = NULL;

    for (i=0; i<num; i++) {
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, tpool_worker, tm);
        pthread_detach(thread);
    }

    return tm;
}


void tpool_destroy(tpool_t *tm)
{
    tpool_work_t *work;
    tpool_work_t *work2;

    if (tm == NULL)
        return;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(tm->work_mutex));
    work = tm->work_first;
    while (work != NULL) {
        work2 = work->next;
        tpool_work_destroy(work);
        work = work2;
    }
    tm->stop = true;
    pthread_cond_broadcast(&(tm->work_cond));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tm->work_mutex));

    tpool_wait(tm);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&(tm->work_mutex));
    pthread_cond_destroy(&(tm->work_cond));
    pthread_cond_destroy(&(tm->working_cond));

    free(tm);
}


bool tpool_add_work(tpool_t *tm, thread_func_t func, void *arg)
{
    tpool_work_t *work;

    if (tm == NULL)
        return false;

    work = tpool_work_create(func, arg);
    if (work == NULL)
        return false;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(tm->work_mutex));
    if (tm->work_first == NULL) {
        tm->work_first = work;
        tm->work_last  = tm->work_first;
    } else {
        tm->work_last->next = work;
        tm->work_last       = work;
    }

    pthread_cond_broadcast(&(tm->work_cond));
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tm->work_mutex));

    return true;
}


void tpool_wait(tpool_t *tm)
{
    if (tm == NULL)
        return;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&(tm->work_mutex));
    while (1) {
        if ((!tm->stop && tm->working_cnt != 0) || (tm->stop && tm->thread_cnt != 0)) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&(tm->working_cond), &(tm->work_mutex));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(tm->work_mutex));
}
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "tpool.h"

static const size_t num_threads = 4;
static const size_t num_items   = 24;

void worker(void *arg)
{
    int *val = arg;
    int  old = *val;

    *val += 1000;
    printf("tid=%p, old=%d, val=%d\n", pthread_self(), old, *val);

    if (*val%2)
        usleep(100000);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    tpool_t *tm;
    int     *vals;
    size_t   i;

    tm   = tpool_create(num_threads);
    vals = calloc(num_items, sizeof(*vals));

    for (i=0; i<num_items; i++) {
        vals[i] = i;
        tpool_add_work(tm, worker, vals+i);
    }

    tpool_wait(tm);

    /*for (i=0; i<num_items; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", vals[i]);
    }*/

    free(vals);
    tpool_destroy(tm);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question you need to answer is why `tpool_wait`  isn't waiting. What condition is different than expected? This is a simple debugging task.

Comment: No... For any number of tasks, the void worker(void *arg) function must be called to process the task. But with a small number of tasks, this function is not called. This is the main problem. I want to understand why this is happening

Comment: But isn't the reason it's not called because the program exited without waiting? If no, what's the reason? Again, simple debugging task. Find out what's blocking that shouldn't, or what's not blocking that should. Do it, then come back with the missing info.

Comment: You are probably incrementing `working_cnt` in the wrong place. You should probably increment it in `tpool_add_work()` instead of in `tpool_worker()`. This will account for jobs that have been added but not yet seen by a worker thread.

Comment: Please avoid posting pictures of text, you can copy text from your terminal using Ctrl+Shift+C

Comment: BTW, "tpool.c" is missing the line `#include <stdlib.h>` needed to declare `calloc` and `free`.

Comment: thank you very much, the problem really turned out to be in increment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a thread scheduling race between `tm->working_cnt++;` in `tpool_worker()` and testing `tm->working_cnt!=0` in `tpool_wait()`. To fix it, `working_cnt` should be incremented at the time the work is added to the pool in `tpool_add_work()` instead of incrementing it at the time a worker thread has unqueued the work in `tpool_worker()`.  The race can be fixed by moving the `tm->working_cnt++;` line to `tpool_add_work()` somewhere between the locking and unlocking of `tm->work_mutex`.

---

By the way, **tpool.c** needs the line `#include <stdlib.h>` to declare `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `free()`.

Comment: I looked at this question before I started working today and thought the integration of the work queue into the thread pool was waaaay more complex than it needed to be but didn't have the time to figure out the specifics.  IMO it should just use a separate queue implementation that can be tested thoroughly completely independent of the thread pool.